# Transfer switch worked but only to half the house, used to work fine. Any ideas? Thanks

Tags: generator, transfer-switch

We have a generac 20k generator and auto transfer switch. It has worked well for 3 years, but now when the power goes out it only switches over half the house. Any suggestions on troubleshooting would be very appreciated.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Is this a 240VAC dual phase generator? Would you post a diagram of the wiring? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: What is the manufacturer and model of the transfer switch?

Comment: What country and state or province is the house in?

Comment: Is this transfer switch a service entrance type (i.e. ahead of the main panel?)

Comment: What ever it is you have lost either 1 leg of the generator or 1 leg of the transfer switch. Voltage measurements at the generator output and transfer switch need to be made. It can be a bad connection a bad breaker or transfer switch connection. More info is needed to help further.